# Rails concerns: class method with block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to write class method **my_method** (like a **validate**), that uses code block.

Model contains next code:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Usable
  my_method :arg_1, :arg_2

  my_method do |model|
    # just for example 
    if model.attribute.present?
      :arg3
    else
      :arg4
    end
  end
  #...
end
```

**my_method** is class method defined in concern:

```
module Usable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # instance methods
  def instance_method
    self.class.display_attrs
  end
  # ...

  module ClassMethods
    #  class methods
    def display_attrs
      @attrs_for_display ||= []
    end

    def my_method(*attr_names, &block)
      attr_names.each do |attr|
        attr_data = { attr: attr }
        display_attrs << attr_data
      end

      display_attrs << { attr: block} if block_given? 
    end
  end
end
```

Instance method @model.instance_method works fine when arguments putted in **my_method** directly `my_method :arg_1, :arg_2`

```
> Model.last.instance_method
=> [{:attr=>:arg_1}, {:attr=>:arg_2}]
```

But **instance_method** returns a Proc object when **my_method** uses block `my_method {:arg_3}`

```
> Model.last.instance_method
=>[{:attr=>   #<Proc:0x00 ... >}]
```

How to put in **my_method** arguments in according of instance state? For example, `@model.instance_method` should return :arg_3 if `model.attribute.present?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved with [call method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Method.html#method-i-call).
I rewrote instance_method as follows:

```
  def instance_method
    class_attrs = self.class.display_attrs.map { |n| n[:attr] }
    class_blocks = self.class.display_attrs.map { |n| n[:block].call(self) if n[:block] }
    (class_attrs + class_blocks).compact!
  end

  module ClassMethods
  #...
       display_attrs << { block: block} if block_given?
  #...
  end
```